# JQuery won't dynamically append html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically manipulate elements in my html page but I bumped into a problem.
I used to able to append or remove an element but out of sudden I can't anymore. 
I must be doing something wrong here...

```
<div  id="multiUploaderTop"> 
    <div><input type="button" value="add more files" id="buttonAddFile1"></div>
    <div id="multiUploaderContainer">
    <div><input type="file" name="attachment"/></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The above is the piece of html that I want to manipulate.
And below is the jquery script that I'm running. 
What am I doing wrong ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("doc ready");
    initMultiUpload();
});

function initMultiUpload(){
    $("#buttonAddFile1").bind("click", function(){

        try{
            addNewFileRow();

        }catch(exception){
            alert(exception.message);
        }


    });
}

function addNewFileRow(){
    try{
        alert("adding new file row");
        var container = $("#multiUploadContainer");
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var fileInput = document.createElement("input");
        $(fileInput).attr("type", "file");
        $(fileInput).attr("name", "attachment");
        $(div).append(fileInput);
        $(container).append(div);
    }catch(ex){
        alsert(ex.message);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: r u looking for jquery clone check this out..http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake, `multiUploaderContainer` and `multiUploadContainer`

```
var container = $("#multiUploaderContainer");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fj2mg/)

It can be simplified much to

```
function addNewFileRow() {
    var container = $("#multiUploaderContainer");
    var div = $('<div />');
    var fileInput = $('<input />', {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'attachment'
    }).appendTo(div);
    container.append(div);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N4Gfb/)

Comment: ugh! I feel so stupid, thx for your quick answer. It was a typo all along.